# Can a bracelet fitted to hand, slip off and stay connected?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Hello I have a bracelet in my hand with a clip that holds it connected. The bracelete can not slip off my wrist, it is not loose. However while I was standing, it felt from my hand and I found it still connected on the floor.

I don't believe in magic and I am not making any fun out of this. I am a physics/mechanics enthusiast and I am trying to think of a possible logical reason, how this can happen.

Thank you.

this is how the connector is

[image: this is how the connector is]

Comment: This does not seem to be a physics question.

Comment: Look closely at the chain. One of the links is probably broken and has a C shape instead of that of a closed O. The chain opened and fell from your arm. But there was a tiny probability that that link engaged itself with the next one by chance when the chain touched the ground. It won't happen again.

Comment: If you observe the same phenomenon a second time, then it is time to quit smoking marijuana.

Comment: No, miracles happen. Believe me.

Comment: If things like this happen to you usually, it could be the beginning of a brain disorder, and the best you can do is going to a psychriatist as soon as possible, and this time I am not joking. Please don't ignore this. Many times they can help very much. Good luck, friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly it *can* slip from your wrist :)

There's no special physics that would make the bracelet do something weird. (I'm assuming your hand wasn't stuck in an oven at the time, which might cause the metal to expand.)

When testing if it would fall off, try wriggling it more, and try changing the shape of your hand. Just because your fingers are spread too wide for it to fall off in one configuration doesn't mean it can't do so in another. The fact that the human brain is not necessarily good at imagining possible reconfigurings that allow objects to separate is precisely the reason [tavern puzzles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tavern_puzzle) can be challenging.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried several times, many many combinations but as I said, the bracelet is not loose to my wrist. I hope that you will reply, and do not get it as a funny post. The easy way to me is to say that "things happen" but because I do not belive in "this things" I bet on a physicist opinion.